# AMD R5 M240 drivers for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my thinkpad E555 with AMD R5 M240(kaveri) but i cant find 
any drivers and i think they are not automatically installed because at system details as Graphics is: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe(LLVM 3.5 m 128bits) and  the interface is laggy.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried launching 'Additional Drivers' from the menu? In some cases there will be proprietary drivers available there which you can install.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Answer (score 0):

The AMD Radeon R5 M240 seems to require at least Kernel 3.15 and Mesa 10.3. So you have the following options:

1. Update to Ubuntu 14.10 or newer.
2. Install a fresh Trusty point release 14.04.**2** or
3. Update your kernel and mesa with LTSEnablementStack, e.g. (using aptitude)

   ```
   sudo aptitude install linux-generic-lts-utopic  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
   ```

See the [bug 1410205](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1410205) and the explanation of [LTSEnhancementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Comment: There are kernels 3.16 and 3.19 for 14.04.

Comment: Well, probably you could also install mesa 10.3 with Ubuntu 14.04, but with Ubuntu 14.10, it will run out of the box.

Comment: In 14.04.2 it is out of the box. And kernel 3.16.

Comment: Thanks to pilot6, I have learnt about LTS Enablement and edited my answer. Hopefully, it is correct.

Comment: Not 100% correct, but not that bad.